# Blender Traceback error

Tags: python

When I try to import a certain obj file, I get this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zelor\OneDrive\Documents\blender-2.79-rc2-windows64\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj__init__.py", line 148, in execute
    return import_obj.load(context, **keywords)
  File "C:\Users\Zelor\OneDrive\Documents\blender-2.79-rc2-windows64\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 1258, in load
    unique_material_images, use_image_search, use_cycles, float_func)
  File "C:\Users\Zelor\OneDrive\Documents\blender-2.79-rc2-windows64\2.79\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 293, in create_materials
    mtl = open(mtlpath, 'rb')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Zelor\Desktop\Halo 5 Textures Tga Format\Armors\Nightfall\Nightfall'

location: :-1"

And I cant seem to fix it. Its becoming quite frustrating. It happens in every version of blender that I have installed.
Even In administrator mode it still has this error.

Comment: Hi, the error is clearly "Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Zelor\Desktop\Halo 5 Textures Tga Format\Armors\Nightfall\Nightfall'", so have you checked the path, it seems it should have textures in it...?

Comment: It has textures in the path, they are not assigned to the mesh. I have the mesh in the folder, then the textures in another folder within that folder.